# How FB refreshes the page without reloading it (xmlHttpRequest) but Back button still works?

Tags: facebook, xmlhttprequest, back-button, page-refresh

How FB refreshes the page without reloading it (xmlHttpRequest) but Back/Forward Buttons still work as usual?

It's not about using `history.pushState()` methods. `PushState()` only changes URL-string but does nothing to get previous looking page after you click Back Button. So it's smth different.

Here's my code and example.

I have such site (look at the pic below). Header-div and Content-div. At the begining when you first time open it, the URL is `mysite.com/page1.php.` I want to change content in Content-div without reloading page. Just new info should appear in Content-div. And the URL should change to `mysite.com/page2.php`.

Here's HTML-code.

```
<div id="content"></div>

<a href="" id="relaodLink">Reload Content</a>
```

Here's JS-code to it.

```
document.getElementById("relaodLink").onclick = function() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "page2.php", true);
    xmlHttp.send();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So Header should not reload after pressing `relaodLink`, just content in Content-div changes. And most important: URL should change like page was really reloaded. Back Button allows to go to `mysite.com/page1.php` and then Forward Button allows to go back to `mysite.com/page2.php` again. With `history.pushState()` methods it doesn't work. But in FB Back and Forward Buttons work fine. How to make it?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [ljplus.ru](http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/a/_/a_ya_vishe/primer-xmlhttp_3.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent question. If you observe, you can notice that the back buttons and forward buttons will work in gmail also though it is completely built on Ajax.

The browser back and forward buttons work on storing what is there in the address bar. So in Ajax, if you never change what is there in the address bar, it doesn't go into the history and hence back and forward buttons don't work.

For this to work, you need to append something to the address bar constantly.
For example : In **gmail**,
When Inbox is clicked - https://mail.google.com/mail/?**tab=mm#inbox**
When Starred is clicked - https://mail.google.com/mail/?**tab=mm#starred**
When Sent is clicked - https://mail.google.com/mail/?**tab=mm#sent**

So in this way, **gmail** keeps appending to address bar. Hence history is preserved. The same goes with **facebook** also. Though the page is not refreshed, the location in address bar changed - that's the key here !!

I hope it helps you !

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. To change the address in address bar i do this `window.location.hash = "#page2";`. So, the result is the same as with `history.pushState()` - the url changes, one step in history appears but it doesn't make previous looking page. Only adress bar changes from one to another `mysite.com/page1.php` to `mysite.com/page1.php#page2` and back. The content stays the same.

Comment: @GuruC Does anyone have any more information on this? Im unsure how to get this to work.

Comment: When I am chatting and click one link from the left side menu the URL changes completely (Not only the # part) but the chat menu never flickers. I m not sure if its happening too fast, because if i normally click refresh i notice the page reload.